# scroll spy to more than one navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an one page site with bootstrap 4 and a i would like to apply bootstrap scroll spy to both my main navigation and to a side "navbar" with bullets. I applied scroll spy to the main navigation but i can't figure out how to do it with the side bar. Also if I change the `data-target=".navbar"` to `data-target="#bulletNav"` again it is not working. Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2beqhxxe/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the response is in Scrollspy.js, this component handle only link in the "target" which have .nav-link or .list-group-item class (see below the guilty code ;-) ).
Here is the jsfiddle solution for multiple scrollspy like you want: https://jsfiddle.net/airpanda50/7ymL4f11/

```
const Selector = {
    DATA_SPY        : '[data-spy="scroll"]',
    ACTIVE          : '.active',
    NAV_LIST_GROUP  : '.nav, .list-group',
    NAV_LINKS       : '.nav-link',
    LIST_ITEMS      : '.list-group-item',
    DROPDOWN        : '.dropdown',
    DROPDOWN_ITEMS  : '.dropdown-item',
    DROPDOWN_TOGGLE : '.dropdown-toggle'
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Another problem I noticed is that it starts with contact(the last link) active and when i scroll then it marks the actual active link...

Comment: Yes I noticed too, but it's because you gave a height to the section tags in the javascript  document.ready so when scrollspy is initiate, all the sections are empty and 0 height. I changed the code in the jsfiddle:
- desactive all the javascript instruction
- add a rule in CSS: sections { height: 100vh;}
So now the section tags have a height when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks now it is as it should be